# $\partial_xF+F\partial_yF=0$ implies that $F$=const

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, linear-pde

Let $F\in \mathit{C}^2(\mathbb{R^2},\mathbb{R})$ and $$\partial_xF+F\partial_yF=0.$$
How do I prove that $F$ is a constant on $\mathbb{R^2}$? I am trying to restrict $F$ to a line passing through the origin and prove that the values of $F$ on the line equal $F(0,0)$, but failed.

Comment: The solutions to Burger's equation are not all constant, your claim is not specific enough. Or perhaps it is specific in that the function is $C^2$ on all of $\Bbb R^2$, then you need to cleverly use that no characteristic curves can ever intersect, neither in positive nor in negative time.

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann Can you give a counterexample?

Comment: The first sentence was to your attempt to solve the problem by local considerations, as local twice differentiable solutions exist. You need to make global arguments from the start, essentially you have to show that the characteristic curves, which are lines, have to be all parallel. As slope is here connected to value, the claim follows.

Answer (score 3):

Claim: If $F(x_0,y_0)=c$, then $F(x,y)=c$ for all $(x,y)$ satisfying $y=y_0+c(x-x_0)$. Indeed, $$\frac d{dx}F(x,y_0+c(x-x_0))=\partial_xF+c\partial_yF=(c-F)\partial_yF.$$ Since $\partial_yF$ is locally bounded, we therefore have (after restricting to a compact set $K$) $$|\frac d{dx}(c-F)|\leq C|c-F|$$ where we are saying $C$ is $\sup_K|\partial_yF|$. Then by Gronwall’s inequality, we conclude that $F=c$ on the part of this line contained in $K$. Picking a sequence of compact sets that exhaust the plane, we conclude that $F=c$ on the whole line.

Now suppose there are two points $(x_0,y_0)$ and $(x_1,y_1)$ such that $F(x_0,y_0)=c_0$, $F(x_1,y_1)=c_1$. Then by the above claim, $F=c_0$ on a line of slope $c_0$ and $F=c_1$ on a line of slope $c_1$. If $c_0\neq c_1$ these lines would intersect and produce a contradiction, so we must have $c_0=c_1$.

It seems we have only assumed $F\in C^1(\mathbb R^2)$.